# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.w3c.tidy.Tidy.setHideComments error in Maven project

Tags: java, maven, maven-2

I am having a Maven project. When I run the project I am getting error. The cause of the error is

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.w3c.tidy.Tidy.setHideComments(Z)V
```

I thought jar might be missing in Maven repository. But I found the jar in that repository.

I have `jtidy-4aug2000r7-dev.jar at C:\.m2\repository\jtidy\jtidy\4aug2000r7-dev`

Can some one tell the probable reason for the problem.

Comment: Where exactly are you getting this error?

Comment: @AndrewLogvinov When I try to browse some pages in my web application. I am getting this as log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the problem might be with the version of the `jtidy.jar`. The current version you have mentioned is quite old (Aug 4, 2000).

I have googled the version `4aug2000r7-dev.jar` and found out 
[API](http://grepcode.com/snapshot/repo1.maven.org/maven2/jtidy/jtidy/4aug2000r7-dev).

I don't see `setHideComments()` method in [Tidy.java](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/jtidy/jtidy/4aug2000r7-dev/org/w3c/tidy/Tidy.java?av=f)

Please check you do not have multiple version of the same jar.

Try `JTidy 8.0-SNAPSHOT` [here](http://www.soapui.org/repository/maven2/jtidy/jtidy/8.0-SNAPSHOT/). It contains the method.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I found a latest jar with the method mentioned above. can you tell me how do I replace it .m2 repository.

Comment: Its another question. You need to edit `pom.xml`. Try Google or SO for more deails.

Answer (score 1):

A `NoSuchMethodError` occurs when you load a A class that requires a method on class B that doesn't exist in the version of B that the the JVM has loaded.  In this case, the JVM is expecting to find a non-private method with the signature `void setHideComments(boolean)` ... but it isn't there.

There are three common causes:

- You have changed or removed the method in B and recompiled B ... but nor A.
- You have the wrong version of some library JAR file; e.g. the JAR containing A depends on a different version of the JAR containing B than the one you have listed as a dependency.
- A variant of the previous one is that somehow you have two versions of one or other of the JAR files on the execution classpath.

Assuming that you aren't modifying jtidy, the first explanation does not apply.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I am using the older version of Jar which does not have that method. Now I have got the newer jar, but I don't how to update in .m2 repository. Can you tell me how do I fix it.

Comment: You shouldn't do it that way.  You should edit your project's POM file so that the dependency refers to the specific version that you need.

Answer (score 0):

Most possibly that your jar file is quite old (Aug 4, 2000) and could be that those method was added later. Try to use this [jar](http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/pub/mirrors/maven2/net/java/dev/ajax4jsf/ajax4jsf/1.0.6/ajax4jsf-1.0.6.jar)